# Problems with creating a scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I would like to solve the following problem in matplotlib/Python:

- Create a scatter plot of size 8x8.
  Plot each datapoint of a cluster  ∈
  x
  i
  k
  ∈
  C
  k
  as dots with an alpha value of 0.6 and a label.
- The plot-label should contain both the cluster's letter-label as well as its integer-label.
- Further, plot the cluster's mean  
  μ
  k
  as a red cross of size 7. The plot should also have a label for each cluster's mean, giving information on its exact coordinates.
- The title of the plot should be 'Scatter plot of the clusters' in fontsize 20.
- Label for the scatter plots example: A = 0
- Label for the cluster means example (use LaTeX):  :
  μ
  A
  :
  [1.23 0.56]
- If the mean of each cluster is not provided, use calc_means(clusters) to calculate the means.
  Number of loops allowed in this exercise: 1 (for iteration over the clusters)

This should be the structure of the function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

def plot_scatter_and_mean(
clusters: List[np.ndarray],
letters: List[str],
means: Optional[List[np.ndarray]] = None,
) -> None:
```

Here are the arguments explained:

```
Args:
    clusters (List[np.ndarray]): A list containing arrrays representing 
    each cluster
    letters (List[str]): The "name" of each cluster
    means (Optional[List[np.ndarray]]): The mean of each cluster. If not
    provided the mean of each cluster in `clusters` should be calculated and 
    used
```

Unfortunately, I have not yet much experience with scatter plots and I'm a little bit lost here.

This is what I have:
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

```
for i in clusters:
    point = data[i] #the element ith in data
    x = point[0] #the first coordenate of the point, x
    y = point[1] #the second coordenate of the point, y
    plt.scatter(x,y, alpha = 0.6) #plot the point
```

Example Data for clusters would be:

```
   [array([[0.8, 0.7],
   [0.3, 0.1]]), array([[0. , 0.4]])]

   --> Here we have two different clusters, one with two points and one with one point.
```

However, I get the following failure message for the line "point = clusters[I]":

```
   only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Can you help me to sort this out so that I'm able to plot the scatter plot?

Comment: Moreover, I'd like to point out that, even if you will provide sufficient context, I won't provide an answer because you have not shown (at least to me) the minimum of effort that is usually required...  look at Matplotlib gallery (Google "matplotlib gallery") study an example, make your try and come here with your problems...

Comment: I‘ve added what I have, it would already help me to know how to finish the first scatter plot. I also have no more context for this task.

Comment: You should probably provide first what the function is doing, before anyone could help you!
Also, with what you have provided above, the error comes from `clusters` where it should be `range(len(clusters))`